# Variable * Time.deltaTime always return just Time.deltaTime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently making a code for a screen pan when the mouse is over the boundary. The code works, but no matter the float speed value, it scrolls at the same speed (I have tried immense values such as 3000000 just to check), from what I checked online I'm using Time.deltaTime correctly, so I have no idea what is happening.

```
public static bool isOnMap = true;
public GameObject CameraObject;
public int Boundary = 50; // distance from edge scrolling starts
public float speed = 1f;
private int theScreenWidth;
private int theScreenHeight;
public static float MapWidth;
public static float MapHeight;

public float Velocity ()
{
    float velocity;
    velocity = speed * Time.smoothDeltaTime;
    Debug.Log(velocity);
    return velocity;
}

void Start()
{
    theScreenWidth = Screen.width;
    theScreenHeight = Screen.height;

}
void Update()
{   
    //mouse
    #region
    if (isOnMap && Input.mousePosition.x > theScreenWidth - Boundary)
    {
        if (transform.position.x >= MapWidth)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + Velocity(), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    if (isOnMap && Input.mousePosition.x < 0 + Boundary)
    {
        if (transform.position.x <= 5)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - Velocity(), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    if (isOnMap && Input.mousePosition.y > theScreenHeight - Boundary)
    {
        if (transform.position.y >= MapHeight + 5)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + Velocity(), transform.position.z);
        }
    }
    if (isOnMap && Input.mousePosition.y < 0 + Boundary)
    {
        if (transform.position.y <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - Velocity(), transform.position.z);
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you changing the `speed` value inside the code or in the inspector?. Keep in mind that the variable `speed` is going to take the value on the inspector.

Comment: Oh my good... yes it's public... ¬¬ hahaha Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change like below. Also change the `speed` from `1` for change of overall speed.

```
public float Velocity ()
{
    return speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```